# How to put JS var as part of an Element's attribute, using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to coding, and as a learning experience I've decided to make a little project.

I'm trying to modify an element's CSS style using JS, but i'm struggling with putting a JS variable as part of one of the arguments:

`document.getElementById("squareContainer").setAttribute('"style","width:'+gridWidth+'*30 px"');`

squareContainer is a div, and gridWidth is a JS variable with a value of a natural number larger than 0.

The goal is to set squareContainer's width attribute to be gridWidth*30 pixels wide, but console shows this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
    at life.html:33
```

I know it's because of the way I put single- and double-quotes in there, but I have no idea how to actually fix it. I've tried many combinations, but they don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be passing just a single value to the `setAttribute` function. To fix this issue, you will have to get rid of the outer single quotes.

```
document.getElementById("squareContainer").setAttribute("style", "width:" + gridWidth * 30 + "px");
```

**BONUS TIP:**

As a better and clean alternative to string concatenation, you may use template strings for string interpolation, i.e., embedding a JS variable inside a string. Template strings use a backtick character (`` ` ``) instead of usual quotation marks (`'` or `"`). You can rewrite the above line of code using template string as such:

```
document.getElementById("squareContainer").setAttribute("style", `width: ${gridWidth * 30}px`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing only one value. Please try the below

```js
document.getElementById("squareContainer").setAttribute("style","width:" + gridWidth * 30 + "px");
```

if you would like to use ES6

````js
```js
document.getElementById("squareContainer").setAttribute("style",`width: ${gridWidth * 30}px`);
````

```
For more information
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_style.asp
```